# Super Quick CSS&HTML: 2 Nav Bars + Sub Nav

Tags: html, css

i'm currently new to CSS and i hope to get a response for this on how to style a page which has 2 nav bars (side by side).

1 side (nav bar on the left) has :Login and Register

1 side (nav bar on the right) has: Add Merchant, Add Business, Business Centre, Trending (and for Trending, there's a sub menu for Words and Data)

I'm currently unable to:

1. have my right nav bar to sit on the same row as the left nav bar
2. have the sub menu for words and data to fall nicely under Trending

Please help cos i've been trying to figure it out for almost a day!

```
<ul id="navleft">
   <li> <a href='/user/login.php'>Login</a></li>
   <li> <a href='/user/register.php'>Register</a> </li>
</ul>
</nav>

<ul id="navright">
   <li> <a href=/ user/addreview.php>Add Review</a> </li>
   <li> <a href=/ user/addbusiness.php>Add Business</a> </li>
   <li> <a href=/ business/businesscentre.php>Business Centre</a></li>
   <li> <a href=/ user/trending.php>Trending</a>
      <ul id="navrightsub">
         <li> <a href=/ user/trendingwords.php>Words</a> </li>
         <li> <a href=/ user/trendingareas.php>Areas</a> </li>
   </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

CSS Format:

```
a {
   font-family: Arial;
   font-size: 15px;
   text-decoration: none;
   padding: 5px;
}
/* make text bigger and no underline*/

a:hover {
   cursor: pointer;
   color: #ff4500;
}
/* make text change color when hovered over*/

#navleft {
   list-style: none;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: #f5f5f5;
   padding: 5px;
}
/* this is the grey nav bar*/

#navleft li {
   display: inline-block;
}
/* this is the list inside the grey nav bar*/

#navright li {
   list-style: none;
   display:inline-block;
} /*this is the list inside in the navright bar*/

#navrightsub
```

Comment: hows this? http://jsfiddle.net/uegdvob2/

Comment: thanks Kimberly, Suresh has helped me with this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to learn lot of things like, How to use float elements, position proterties and styling so on. I have modified your code and make it working.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="navleft">
 <li> <a href='/user/login.php'>Login</a></li>
 <li> <a href='/user/register.php'>Register</a> </li>
</ul>


<ul id="navright">
 <li> <a href=/ user/addreview.php>Add Review</a> </li>
 <li> <a href=/ user/addbusiness.php>Add Business</a> </li>
 <li> <a href=/ business/businesscentre.php>Business Centre</a></li>
 <li> <a href=/ user/trending.php>Trending</a>
  <ul id="navrightsub">
     <li> <a href=/ user/trendingwords.php>Words</a> </li>
     <li> <a href=/ user/trendingareas.php>Areas</a> </li>
  </ul>    
 </li>   
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
a {
 font-family: Arial;
 font-size: 15px;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding: 5px;
}
a:hover {
 color: #ff4500;
}
#navleft {
 list-style: none;   
 background-color: #f5f5f5;
 padding: 5px;
}
#navleft li {
  display: inline-block;
}
#navright li {
  list-style: none;
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
} 
#navright li ul{display:none;}
#navright li:hover ul{display:block;}
#navright li ul{position:absolute; top:20px; left:-35px;}
#navleft{float:left; padding:0;margin:0;}
#navright{float:right; padding:0; margin:0;}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/o40tn8em/)